# Keep Angular Material table state after Component redirection

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-material, angular-routerlink

I have a *TableComponent* with an Angular Material table that contains some **links to other components**.

[image: Second page of the table]

When I am on the second page of the table (Image above) and I click on the link, `routerLink` redirects to *DetailComponent*. Once I am redirected, if I press the back button or I execute `location.back()` I go back to *TableComponent*, but the table is located on the first page, instead of the one I was before.

[image: First page of the table]

Is there a way to **keep the previous state** of the table, after redirections between components?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know why this question was downvoted. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're redirecting between components, their content is destroyed, so there is no way for a destroyed component to remember anything ;)
But you can store the information about the page index somewhere else in the application (service or store if you're using Redux).

So you can save the page index before redirection i.e. using service or even better just update service after every page change.

Then you can get the index and use `pageIndex` property of `MatPaginator` as described in documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api
to set correct page index after getting back to this page.
Let me know if you need any more help with that.

Comment: Thanks Patryk, that's what I needed to know!

Comment: this was how i did it before (using redux) but i figured it's too cumbersome just for this. seems like there is no other way but to save the table state.